# Angular 6 Can we pass the route parameter between the serives

Tags: javascript, angular

Can we pass the route parameter from one service to another service in Angular 6.

I would like to pass the route parameter from Auth Guard service to Auth Service is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply inject the `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency in your AuthService to get a hold of the route params.

Something along the lines of this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/routes';

export class AuthService {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  yourMethod() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
      const nameOfYourParam = params['nameOfYourParam'];
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry it not working.. In my scenario I have two routing, one is requested routing with parameters and other redirected URL routing. In first routing I can able to get the params I need to pass to redirect routing URL so that I can get it in ActivatedRoute.

Comment: Can you mock this behavior on a [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: Can you please refer this [https://github.com/scottbrady91/Angular4-OidcClientJs-Example/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.service.ts#L43]                                       We are using this authentication, when the user requesting a page we redirect to a authentication page, after authentication the response it redirected to another routing, here I am loosing the request route param